# eTrade API - Downloaded Sample Error: onnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: python, etrade-api

I hope someone can give me a hand here. I am new to python programming, and I downloaded the eTrade API sample and trying to get it to run and I am getting this error. I have alos tried this in C# and VB.NET with no luck.

```
Exception has occurred: ConnectionError
('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  File "C:\Users\kg5fc\Downloads\Bots\etrade_python_client.py", line 63, in oauth
    request_token, request_token_secret = etrade.get_request_token(
                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\kg5fc\Downloads\Bots\etrade_python_client.py", line 111, in <module>
    oauth()
```

Code snip that it errors (Last 2 lines) on:

```
"""This Python script provides examples on using the E*TRADE API endpoints"""
from __future__ import print_function
import webbrowser
import json
import logging
import configparser
import sys
import requests
from rauth import OAuth1Service
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
from accounts.accounts import Accounts
from market.market import Market

# loading configuration file
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')

# logger settings
logger = logging.getLogger('my_logger')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler = RotatingFileHandler("python_client.log", maxBytes=5*1024*1024, backupCount=3)
FORMAT = "%(asctime)-15s %(message)s"
fmt = logging.Formatter(FORMAT, datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
handler.setFormatter(fmt)
logger.addHandler(handler)

print('consumer_key: ' + config["DEFAULT"]["CONSUMER_KEY"])
print('consumer_secret: ' + config["DEFAULT"]["CONSUMER_SECRET"])

def oauth():
    """Allows user authorization for the sample application with OAuth 1"""
    etrade = OAuth1Service(
        name="etrade",
        consumer_key=config["DEFAULT"]["CONSUMER_KEY"],
        consumer_secret=config["DEFAULT"]["CONSUMER_SECRET"],
        request_token_url="https://api.etrade.com/oauth/request_token",
        access_token_url="https://api.etrade.com/oauth/access_token",
        authorize_url="https://us.etrade.com/e/t/etws/authorize?key={}&token={}",
        base_url="https://api.etrade.com")

    menu_items = {"1": "Sandbox Consumer Key",
                  "2": "Live Consumer Key",
                  "3": "Exit"}
    while True:
        print("")
        options = menu_items.keys()
        for entry in options:
            print(entry + ")\t" + menu_items[entry])
        selection = input("Please select Consumer Key Type: ")
        if selection == "1":
            base_url = config["DEFAULT"]["SANDBOX_BASE_URL"]
            break
        elif selection == "2":
            base_url = config["DEFAULT"]["PROD_BASE_URL"]
            break
        elif selection == "3":
            break
        else:
            print("Unknown Option Selected!")
    print("")

    # Step 1: Get OAuth 1 request token and secret
    request_token, request_token_secret = etrade.get_request_token(
        params={"oauth_callback": "oob", "format": "json"})
```

I have googled, chatGPT, and everything I can think of to find a solution.

Comment: Did you discover how to resolve this?  I'm getting similar issues with the first get_request_token call.  I saw this in the Python example.  I just started working with the Java example, which also produced an exception, however I haven't dug in enough to see what specifically about the call is causing it yet.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and found the answer in this [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/etrade/comments/1398aha/etrade_developer_api_fail/). I ran the steps in the last comment (pip uninstall urllib3 and then ran pip install urllib3==1.26.16) and got past this issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).